# Layout log error when use "move" action

Tags: magento2, layout, frontend

I have overwritten the 2columns-left layout by positioning a container using the move action and then assign the order in one of the containers.

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
<update handle="1column"/>
<move element="main" destination="columns.inner" before="-" />
<referenceContainer name="columns">
    <container name="columns.inner" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="columns-inner" before="-">
        <container name="div.sidebar.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-main" after="main">
            <container name="sidebar.main" as="sidebar_main" label="Sidebar Main"/>
        </container>
        <container name="div.sidebar.additional" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-additional" after="div.sidebar.main">
            <container name="sidebar.additional" as="sidebar_additional" label="Sidebar Additional"/>
        </container>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

This throws the following error in system.log.

> main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'div.sidebar.main' tries to reorder itself towards 'main', but their parents are different: 'columns.inner' and 'columns' respectively. [] []

I guess it's because the move action is the last action in queue when rendering.

How can I remove this error?. Can I change the order of the rendering actions?

Comment: What is your override path?

Comment: Magento_Theme/page_layout/override/base/2colums-left.xml

Comment: I had the same problem and looking for a solution, I found this: 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3507 in the last comment okorshenko said that this error will be solved in the release 2.2 and in this link https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/9092 change  log level from critical to info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an acknowledge issue of Magento 2.1, basically it is not an **ERROR** at all.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5627

This pull request will fix the problem: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/9092

It will change the log level from CRITICAL to INFO. There is nothing to worry about these logs at all, your site will works fine.

Hope it helps :)